# javascript calculate total from dropdown and checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to calculate total from multiple dropdown and checkboxes .
This code working fine for the select:option dropdown but my problem is adding the input checked to it.

Here is the code i use: " just need it to calculate the checked boxes along with the selected dropdown "

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var basePrice = 0;

  $(".calculate").change(function() {
    newPrice = basePrice;
    $(".calculate option:selected").each(function() {
      newPrice += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
      console.log(typeof newPrice);
    });

    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="type2" name="service" class="calculate">
    <option data-price="0" value="">-- Select --</option>
    <option data-price="100" value="kite1">wash</option>
    <option data-price="150" value="kite1">wash and dry</option>
    <option data-price="1000" value="kite2">repair</option>
  </select>


<input type="checkbox" class="calculate" data-price="300" name="vehicle" value="Bike">roof
<input type="checkbox" class="calculate" data-price="200" name="vehicle" value="rims">rims


<span id="item-price">0</span>
```

Comment: Looks like you need to bind a click handler to your checkboxes to actually update the price. Right now it's trying to add everything together on page load. `$('.calculate').on('click', function(e){ //use e to get the data element and add to total })`

Comment: i need to tell the java code to look for the checked boxed and calculate them along with the drop down , for now it only look for the options:selected $(".calculate option:selected").each(function ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments inline for explanations:

```js
// Instead of window.load, you can get your function to run earlier
// by setting it up for when the DOM is ready. As long as the function 
// doesn't rely on externally loaded content, this is generally a 
// better idea because the page becomes interactive quicker. 
// Do that by just passing your callback function to JQuery:
$(function(){

  // You need to run the function when the select gets changed but also when the
  // checkboxes get clicked. Now, you could use a simple selector to get references
  // to all the elements in question here, but this could cause other elements that 
  // are not related to this operation to be erroneously included. It's better to 
  // be specific with selectors so that the code can scale.
  // Also, modern JQuery recommends the use of the "on" method for event binding.
  $("select.calculate").on("change", calc);
  $("input[type=checkbox].calculate").on("click", calc);
  
  function calc() {
   var basePrice = 0;
    newPrice = basePrice;
    // You need to loop over, not only the selected option, but also the checked checboxes
    $("select.calculate option:selected, input[type=checkbox].calculate:checked").each(function () {
      newPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });

    newPrice = newPrice.toFixed(2);
    $("#item-price").html(newPrice);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select  id="type2" name="service" class="calculate" >
<option data-price="0" value="">-- Select --</option>
<option data-price="100" value="kite1">wash</option>
<option data-price="150" value="kite1">wash and dry</option>
<option data-price="1000" value="kite2">repair</option>
</select> 


<input type="checkbox"  class="calculate" data-price="300" name="vehicle" value="Bike">roof
<input type="checkbox"  class="calculate" data-price="200" name="vehicle" value="rims">rims


<span id="item-price">0</span>
```